# htaccess rewrite if file doesn't exist issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I use the following three lines to apply a Rewrite rule only if the file does not exist.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /outputchart.php [L]
```

It works fine if the missing file extension is PHP but it if the file is jpg, the page returns 404.

I don't understand why.

Comment: Is this _all_ the rewriting you have configured, or is there more?

Comment: probably php replying that 404, check the response headers to make sure it is not php. Also `FallbackResource /outputchart.php` would be more desirable than that old and dated recipe.

Comment: this is the only code, nothing else in the file

Comment: @ezra-s how do I know if 404 from PHP or Apache?